# How to create a Custom Expiration Action with input parameters

Tags: 2010, custom-actions, expiration, information-policy, retention

I'm currently creating custom expiration formulas and actions, using the IExpirationFormula and IExpirationAction interfaces, in Sharepoint 2010.

I add the custom action to the PolicyResourceCollection using this manifest:

```
string xmlManifest =
"<PolicyResource xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:server:policy\"" +
" id = \"CustomExpirationAction\"" +
" featureId=\"Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Expiration\"" +
" type = \"Action\">" +
"<Name>Custom Expiration Action</Name>" +
"<Description>Custom Expiration Action</Description>" +
"<AssemblyName>" + typeof(CustomControls.CustomExpirationAction).Assembly.FullName + "</AssemblyName>" +
"<ClassName>" + typeof(CustomControls.CustomExpirationAction).FullName  + "</ClassName>" +
"</PolicyResource>";
```

All is working fine but now we need to include in the manifest input parameters, like the "Transfer to another location" action does (parameters in red):

[image]

I came across de XML Manifest schema and it accepts a "GlobalConfigPage" tag and a "GlobalCustomData" tag (documented in http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Custom-debafcff) but i couldn't find an example anywhere.

I know i have to create a Control that inherits from "CustomSettingsControl" but i don't know what to do from there. Any ideas? Is it possible?

Thank you!